# Playwright set the executablePath with MS Test

Tags: c#, playwright

I have a written a real simple test using MSTest.  However, when I try to run the test on a QA server, which is running an old windows version.  Currently, I'm getting the following error message:
"Initialization method PlaywrightTests.scripts.loginPageTests.BrowserSetup threw exception. Microsoft.Playwright.TargetClosedException: Target page, context or browser has been closed"
Here is my code

```
[TestClass]
public class loginPageTests : PageTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task shouldLogUserIn()
    {
        await Page.GotoAsync("https://*MyURL*/");
    }
}
```

I believe, I need to run on an older version of chrome as the current OS doesn't suppor the most recent version.  I believe I have to update the Environment variable ExecutablePath.  I've tried to update in my runsettings file, but it doesn't seem to be working.  My file looks like

```
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
        <HEADED>1</HEADED>
    <EXECUTABLEPATH>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-939194\chrome-win\chrome.exe</EXECUTABLEPATH>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.